# install GNU GSL and RDieHarder on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I need to install **RDieHarder** package in **R** on my Linux Mint. I got some errors during

```
install.packages("RDieHarder")
```

in R.

In documentaion of **RDieHarder** on cran I found some requierments for this package:

> DieHarder library (>= 3.31.1) from
> [http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php](http://www.phy.duke.edu/%7Ergb/General/dieharder.php),
>
> GNU GSL for the GSL random-number generators

I have no idea how to install it on linux (I'm new to linux).

I found GNU GSL and DieHarder under this links:

https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/

[http://webhome.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php](http://webhome.phy.duke.edu/%7Ergb/General/dieharder.php)

Can anybody help with this installations?

Comment: GSL : `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libgsl-dev` https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libgsl-dev

Answer (score 0):

Because you are on Debian-derived distibution, do

```
sudo apt-get install libdieharder-dev libgsl-dev
```

which gets you *both* the Dieharder library *and* the GSL library development packages (and of course the corresponding run-time ones too).

After that, just do

```
R -e 'install.packages("RDieHarder")'
```

and you should be set.